# Google Sheets API Quota Exceeding

Tags: api, google-sheets, gspread

I am creating a Python script that gets information from one API and after some formatting and etc it writes the data in a spreadsheet in Google Sheets. I am using the Gspread library and the script is working tho there is one issue that is actually a 'dealbreaker'. The G Sheets API has limitations of read and write requests per minute or per 100 seconds. The limit is 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. I've been monitoring my request and I have never exceeded this limitation but I get the 429 error - "requests quota exceeded".

So my question would be, could it be the case that 100 request per 100 seconds resonates to 1 request per 1 second so that when my script does 2 or more request in 1 second the 429 error is raised?

What lead me to the thought this could be the case is that I tried using time.sleep with many different values so that I make sure I never exceed even 60 requests per minute but I am still getting the 429 error raised.

Comment: Notice that a single function call maybe making multiple requests. Also, some parts that you may assume don't make any request may be making some. Have you tried the limits while working directly with the REST API?

Comment: @Martí Thanks for the response. Yes, I tested by using the REST API and the limits were looking fine. I can see the number of requests made in the Google APIs Dashboard and it never went above 100 but I am still getting this 429 error raised and it is specifically on the read requests. So do you think that making more than 1 request in a second can cause to raise this error?

Comment: There seems to be no documentation about how much can you do in a single second, but you there is some kind of limit for sure. Usually in cases like this it's recommended to use [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) and exponential backoff after you get the error.

Comment: Also this issue seems to be common in `gspread` so I'd recommend to add that tag as more people will be able to see it (I've made an edit suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

It has a spam protection system which limits to 10 requests per second.
I found out after hours of searching, I was stuck at the same.

You can delay your calls and prevent that.

Comment: Can you please provide any references?